# Rails 3.2 using different CSS page for a few actions in controller (not the whole controller)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, stylesheet

Here's the scenario:

Most of my pages use the CSS from different pages that gets compiled into one big CSS file as per default Rails, no problem there.

But I have a couple of pages that are `actions` in a controller which need to use a different CSS page and not the other ones at all. These are just about 3 actions in a controller that otherwise uses the main, default, compiled CSS.

In order to accomplish this, I call a specific layout for the actions that need the separate page:

```
  format.html { render :layout => 'doghouse_template' }
```

This `doghouse_template` has this call in it its head:

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag "doghouse_page"
```

This works fine in Development where pages are compiled on the fly if necessary but in Production, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (doghouse_page.css isn't precompiled)
```

This is because the `doghouse_page.css` is **not** compiled separately, it is compiled into the main application.css file, so of course, it doesn't exist in the `public/assets` folder.

I should also point out that `doghouse.css` is not really a CSS page but rather **SCSS** so I can't just copy it to `public/assets` without compilation of some type.

My question is, what is the solution here?

I can't use the application.css file for these, let's call them doghouse pages, because it messes the styling up and vice-versa.

I've even tried putting the file into application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( doghouse_page.css.scss )
```

But doesn't make a difference. If, on the other hand, I put:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )
```

I get an error on precompile because of bootstrap/_accordion.scss file so I can't do that.

I've seen very similar questions here but they tend to apply to using different CSS for a whole controller and nowhere does it specify how not to compile all the pages into one.

Please note that I do **not** want to separate all the CSS pages (that would ostensibly be one solution), just this one separate page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do this (note, the lack of .scss, even though doghouse_page.css.scss is your file):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( doghouse_page.css )
```

If you can, I'd consider doing this.  It's worked well for me.  Move doghouse_page.css.scss into an 'extra's folder.  Then:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( extras/*.css )
```

Then in your app/views/layout/application... file add classes to the body tag for the controller and action.  The below is the HAML version of what I use in one of my projects.

```
%body{:class => ["c-#{controller_name}", "a-#{action_name}", I18n.locale]}
```

Then, adjust doghouse_page.css.scss so that it's scoped under a body tag with the right controller/action classes.

In my case I usually just want to override some things or add some things and keep most of what is in application.css.scss.  This might not work for you, but if it does, it's a fairly clean way to customize individual pages/actions.

Comment: Wow, such a simple thing and I never even thought to do this! I tried everything I could think of except this. Adding `.css` instead of `.scss` worked! Thank you so much! I've spent the last 2 days fighting this and had given up and went with `config.assets.compile = true` but this seems to fix it.